# dataTables (jquery) search by two columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, web, datatables

I want to search table by only two columns. E.g. Initial search searches in all columns, I just want to search by two columns.
When I use following code:

```
dataTable.columns([1,7])
    .search("some string")
    .draw();
```

the search text must be present in both columns to be displayed. I want to display it even if it exists in one of the columns. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe [this link](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html) can help you out

Comment: tried to use hints from datatables.net without effect :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED

I've changed searching to initial which searches all columns:

```
dataTable
    .search(this.value)
    .draw();
```

And set columns which I don't want to be search in initTable:

```
    "columnDefs": [
    {
        "targets": [2,5],
        "searchable": false
    }]
```