# Adding merged array to PHP SQL output

Tags: php, datatables

My Datatable talks to an SQL database through a php file. Unfortunately datatables doesn't allow for searching in two columns at the same time, but I'd like to go around that by adding a merged column to the json output of my php file.

Here I'm adding `$arr` but it just says "Column not found":

```
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'Author', 'dt' => 'authors'),
    array( 'db' => 'Editor', 'dt' => 'editor'),
    array( 'db' => 'Item Type', 'dt' => 'type'),
    array( 'db' => 'Publication Year',  'dt' => 'year' ),
    array( 'db' => 'Title',  'dt' => 'title' ),
    array( 'db' => 'Publication Title',  'dt' => 'pubtitle' ),
    array( 'db' => 'Publisher',  'dt' => 'publisher' ),
    array( 'db' => 'Url',  'dt' => 'url'),
    array( 'db' => 'DOI',  'dt' => 'doi' ),
    array( 'db' => 'Title',  'dt' => 'title' ),
    array( 'db' => 'Reviewed Author',  'dt' => 'reviewed' ),
    array( 'db' => 'Abstract Note',  'dt' => 'abstract' ),
    array( 'db' => 'ISBN',  'dt' => 'isbn' ),
    array( 'db' => 'Tags',  'dt' => 'tags'),
    array( 'db' => 'Place',  'dt' => 'place' ),
    array( 'db' => 'Type',  'dt' => 'genre' ),
    array( 'db' => 'Publisher',  'dt' => 'publisher' ),
    array( 'db' => 'Pages',  'dt' => 'pages' ),
    array( 'db' => 'Volume',  'dt' => 'volume' ),
    array( 'db' => 'Issue',  'dt' => 'issue')
);

$arr = array_merge($columns["authors"],$columns["editor"]);

require( 'ssp.class.php' );

echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $arr, $primaryKey, $columns)
);
```

Comment: Top Google Result: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/40164/search-in-multiple-columns

Comment: ...also, `$columns` is an indexed multidimensional array. It doesn't have any keys called `authors` or `editor`. Your code should throw a couple of notices for undefined indexes and a warning for invalid arguments for array_merge. `$arr` should also be null at this point.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33799176/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/28152248/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/43384010/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/43114045/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/49076716/2943403

Comment: @mickmackusa the solutions you're pointing to are javascript, and most of them resort to AND search, where the data has to exist in both columns at the same time, which is not what I'm looking for (i'm looking for OR).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson so the problem is how I call the array within the array? Does that means the merge + adding it to the encode is ok?

Comment: Okay, those were just some of the top search results.  How long have you researched?  Could you please offer some sample data and your desired output?  This helps to clarify your question by adding context.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thank you though. What I want is a json output with an added array, say, `people`, that includes both `authors`, `editor`, and `reviewed`. I can then output it to an hidden column and use it to return searches about `people`.